# display data in gridview using php in a vertical matter

Tags: php, gridview

one fo client needs to display products in a grid sorted alphabetical order.
Display like this.
Products will be queried from the database

```
A  H  O  U
B  I  P  V
C  J  Q  W
D  K  R  X 
E  L  S  Y
```

Rows can be incremented but columns wont be incremented.
maximum number of columns will be 4.
Someone can give an idea to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked into tablesorter plugin?

Comment: no.can you tell me what that is?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @DamForums it is a jquery plugin that will take all of your data that is returned and put it in a nice neat table for you that is sortable.  Just google jquery tablesorter plugin to find it and some examples

Comment: i tried to diplay the alphabet. but the thing is i have know idea how can i integrate the query into that. i just followed a post on stack

Comment: http://codepad.org/DoHo8hVs - a really scruffily coded version for you to work from. Code isn't efficient by any means... but it works.

Comment: @Jim: Yes i am trying it.Will give a update to you.thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got an array of results you want to display it's pretty straight forward. Just calculate the number of rows there will be in each final column (in this case the total number of results to display divided by 4 then rounded up). This then becomes your offset to get the index of the item to go in the next column given the index of the item in the current column.

Something like this will work:

```
<?php
    $rows= array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X');

    $numberOfTableRows= ceil(count($rows)/4.0);
?>
    <table>
<?php   
    for($ndx=0;$ndx<$numberOfTableRows;$ndx++)
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows[$ndx]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo (isset($rows[$ndx+$numberOfTableRows]) ? $rows[$ndx+$numberOfTableRows] : ''); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo (isset($rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*2)]) ? $rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*2)] : ''); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo (isset($rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*3)]) ? $rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*3)] : ''); ?></td>
    </tr>   
<?php   
    }
?>
    </table>
```

**EDIT** Or using data from SQL:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM tbl_user ORDER BY tbl_user.user ASC");

// Build the $rows array from the MySQL results
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[]= $row;  
}

mysql_free_result($result);

$numberOfTableRows= ceil(count($rows)/4.0);
?>
    <table>
<?php   
    for($ndx=0;$ndx<$numberOfTableRows;$ndx++)
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows[$ndx]['user']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo (isset($rows[$ndx+$numberOfTableRows]) ? $rows[$ndx+$numberOfTableRows]['user'] : ''); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo (isset($rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*2)]) ? $rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*2)]['user'] : ''); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo (isset($rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*3)]) ? $rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*3)]['user'] : ''); ?></td>
    </tr>   
<?php   
    }
?>
    </table>
```

So the changes I've made are: we're now looping through the results of the `mysql_query` to build our results array and, in the output section we're now referencing the database field we want to display (as each `$row` will now be an array rather than a single value).

**NOTE** I've used `mysql_*` as that's what you used in your comment, but really we shouldn't be using those anymore as they've been deprecated - use `mysqli_*` (or PDO) instead.

**EDIT** Switching to change the output to `UL`s as requested.

If we're writing to `UL`s it's a little bit easier as we can build the HTML column-wise rather than row-wise. So, using a table to layout the 4 columns we get:

```
<?php
    /** $row generation code as before **/
    $numberOfTableRows= ceil(count($rows)/4.0);
?>
    <table>
    <tr>
<?php
    for($col=0;$col<4;$col++) {
?>
        <td style="vertical-align: top">
        <ul>
<?php
        for($ndx=0;$ndx<$numberOfTableRows;$ndx++)
        {
            if (isset($rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*$col)])) {
?>

        <li><a href="?id=<?php echo $rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*$col)]['user_id'];?>"><?php echo $rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*$col)]['user'];?></li>
<?php
            }
        }
?>
        </ul>
        </td>
<?php   
    }
?>
    </tr>   
    </table>
```

Comment: this works for the Alphabet.but if i use the mysql query to get data, it only display the first Data item in the dynamic table.this is what i did.wrote a query to get users.$sql = mysql_query("SELECT  user FROM tbl_user ORDER BY tbl_user.user ASC"); 
$cath=mysql_fetch_array($sql); and then i pass $cath to $rows.anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Danielpsc.i tried to display all the usrs using ur help. but i faced some problems.can you help on those?.I need to display users in a seperate <ul> tags.every user is listed in a <li> tag. and i have to list their user id in href.this is the code i did.
 <li><a href="<?php echo $rows[$ndx]['user_id']['user_id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows[$ndx]['user']['user']; ?></a></li>.can you plz help me on this?i am stuck in a big way. so there will be 4 ul tags.hiw can i repeat those?

Comment: You shouldn't need to repeat the field names. So something like this should work: `<li><a href="<?php echo $rows[$ndx]['user_id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows[$ndx]['user']; ?></a></li>`. You will, of course, need to add `user_id` to your `SELECT` statement too.

Comment: Assume 25 users in table. then how can i display first 7 users in a first <ul> and second 7 users in a another <ul> tag basically there will be 4 separate <ul> tags.those <ul> tags will be in div tag.how can i do that using this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $rows = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X');

    $numberOfTableRows = ceil(count($rows)/4.0);
?>
    <table>
<?php   
    for($ndx=0;$ndx<$numberOfTableRows;$ndx++)
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows[$ndx]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows[$ndx+$numberOfTableRows]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*2)]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows[$ndx+($numberOfTableRows*3)]; ?></td>
    </tr>   
<?php   
    }
?>
    </table>
```

- Thanks

Comment: this works for the Alphabet.but if i use the mysql query to get data, it only display the first Data item in the dynamic table.this is what i did.wrote a query to get users.$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM tbl_user ORDER BY tbl_user.user ASC"); $cath=mysql_fetch_array($sql); and then i pass $cath to $rows.anything i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is in one dimensional array sorted alphabetically, this will split it into rows as you want(it is working):

```
<?php
# generate alphabet for demo
# warning: php5.5 generator
function az1() { for($a = 65; $a < 91; $a++) { yield chr($a); } }

$a = [];

foreach(az1() as $s) { $a[] = $s; }

# spit data into columns
$size = round(sizeof($a) / 4);


$b = []; 

for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
  $b[] = array_slice($a, $i * $size, $size); 
}

# transform it to rows
$c = [];
for($i  = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
  $c[$i] = [];
  for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
    if(isset($b[$j][$i]))
      $c[$i][$j] = $b[$j][$i];
    else
      $c[$i][$j] = '';
  }
}

print_r($c);
```

Then you can use a regular `foreach` to generate table rows or something you want it to be in.

**EDIT**

Assuming there's some `products` table with columns like that:

```
id | category_id | title | content | image | price | qty
```

And you want to show them all alphabetically(for a certain category or section in your store):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = 5 ORDER BY title ASC
```

It will give you products sorted alphabetically. Then you could feed it to that code above;

Once more, with code:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=store', 'youruser', 'yourpasswd');

$pdo->query('SET NAMES UTF8'); # here we say NO to latin1

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $category_id = (int) $_GET['id'];


  $prepared = $pdo->prepared('SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = :category_ud ORDER BY title ASC');
  $prepared->execute([':category_id' => $category_id]);

  # don't use this in production with large data sets
  $a = $prepared->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  # spit data into columns
  $size = round(sizeof($a) / 4);

  $b = []; 

  for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $b[] = array_slice($a, $i * $size, $size); 
  }

  # transform it to rows
  $c = [];
  for($i  = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $c[$i] = [];
    for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
      if(isset($b[$j][$i]))
        $c[$i][$j] = $b[$j][$i];
      else
        $c[$i][$j] = '';
    }
  }

  # send $c to output code here
}
```

How to output(assuming above code generates row into `$c` array):

```
<? foreach($c as $row): ?>
<tr>
  <? foreach($row as $product): ?>
    <td>
       .. product information
    </td>
  <? endforeach ?>
</tr>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Can you help more on this?.i am a newbie here.how can use a mysql query to get data to display here?but i am using 5.4.7 php

Comment: @DamForums I've updated code, it now should illustrate how it can be done. Please note that I using here `short_open_tags = on` ini setting and `PDO` mysql driver